# Modify beamer title page

Tags: beamer, titles

I want to create a beamer presentation. And I wish to modify the title page on the go. Like my first title page will show the title "Error Correcting Code". When I click next, it should go to a second title page with title "Quantum Error Correcting Code". Is it possible to edit the title of the title page in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\title{Error Correcting Code}
\author{Ritajit Majumdar}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\title{Quantum Error Correcting Code}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]